# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I got a TypeError becuse of this line:

```
screen.blit(spongebob_pic,(int(mx-(spongebob_pic.get_width//2)),int(my-(spongebob_pic.height//2))))
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int

Comment: no, the question is already answered.

Comment: ...I see. I retract my comment. From the review queue I cannot see answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this:

```
spongebob_pic.get_width // 2
```

you wanted to call the method `get_width()` instead:

```
spongebob_pic.get_width() // 2
```

That's why you get that error: **unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int**

You can't divide a function by 2.

Answer (score 0):

`get_width` is a method, to get the width you need to call it like this: `get_width()`.

Usually if you see a verb which is an action, like get, set, etc. this means that this is a function.